Which of the FLS, SLS and GLS approach types are precision and which are non-precision?
Which of the FLS, SLS and GLS approach types are precision and which are non-precision? Also, what is the main factor that causes this difference? It is generally said that vertical guidance is required for precision to be considered, but I think the situation is a little different here.
FLS (FMS Landing System)
SLS (SBAS Landing System)
GLS (GBAS Landing System)


FLS (or IAN on a Boeing) is a mode used to fly non-precision approaches using the same symbology and modes as a precision approach. FLS is never used for precision approaches. It is equivalent to flying an RNP approach to LNAV/VNAV minima. The vertical navigation is typically based on baro VNAV and therefore does not count as external vertical guidance. ICAO now calls this a 3D approach or APV (approach with vertical guidance).
SLS is used to fly LPV approaches. These are now considered Cat I precision approaches. They used to be classified under APV, but ICAO changed the classification sometime around 2012/2013. I'm not sure if the FAA changed their definition as well.
GLS has always been classified as a precision approach. Initially, only Cat I was used for GLS, but since then we also got Cat II GLS approaches, e.g. at Frankfurt (EDDF). GLS approaches are also certified for autolands.

References:

Is LPV considered a precision approach?

Why isn't an LPV SBAS approach considered a precision approach according to ICAO?




While this is all correct I would make one clarification: while GLS and SLS modes are tied exclusively on approaches based on GBAS and SBAS, respectively, and are required to fly that kind of approaches, FLS is merely and overlay guidance calculated by FMS to fly different kind of NPAs. Only APV Baro-VNAV requires use of FLS modes while other NPAs can be also flown with different AP/FD modes. In itself, FLS is not a ”non-precision approach”. It is an aid that can be used to fly several different types of approaches.

@busdriver That's correct, my phrasing was a bit sloppy there. I updated the answer to clarify.

@Bianfable Is it now technically incorrect for them to be called precision or non-precision approaches. For example, should all Operations Manuals now have these phrases removed? What do the parentheses infer in the diagram above?
